# How to convert a video to 4:3 or 16:9 aspect ratio without loss of video quality

Tags: video, resolution, youtube, avi, conversion

I uploaded my video to YouTube and the highest available playback resolution is 360p. This is much lower than what I uploaded. I believe that YouTube isn't making higher resolutions available for my video because of its aspect ratio. The video is 720x400.

How can I convert my video to a different aspect ratio without losing any of the picture or picture quality? I don't care if blank space appears around the video so long as the picture doesn't get stretched horizontally or vertically.

Comment: Operating system?

Comment: I'm using OSX but I can also use Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/):

```
ffmpeg -i mymovie.mpg -ar 22050 -acodec libmp3lame -ab 32K -r 25 -s 320x240 -vcodec flv mytarget.flv
```

ffmpeg has also option i.e.: `-aspect 16:9`